# How can I change the permissions for a channel in discord.js?

Tags: discord.js

I want to change permissions in a channel for everyone. This is my current code:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: "lockdown", // this would be changed to "remove"

  run: async (client, message, args) => {
    message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(r => {
      message.guild.members.cache.forEach(d => {
      r.overwritePermissions([
    {
        id: d.user.id,
        deny: ['SEND_MESSAGES']
    }]);
      })
    })
  }
}
```

This does not work, it changes the permissions for no one and does not do anything. Why?
Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply declare the permissions for the `@everyone` role (which obviously every user has), by setting the id of the role/user you want to update as a Guild object's id property:

```
module.exports = {
  name: "lockdown",

  run: async (client, message, args) => {
    message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(r => {
      r.overwritePermissions([
    {
        id: message.guild.id,
        deny: ['SEND_MESSAGES']
    }]);
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that without using forEach statement on the guild members. All you have to do is the following:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: "lockdown",
  run: (client, message, args) => {
    message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(r => {
      r.overwritePermissions([
    {
        id: message.guild.roles.everyone.id,
        deny: ['SEND_MESSAGES']
    }]);
    })
  }
}
```

I am writing this on mobile, so it is very hard but that should work! Read more about the `@everyone` role here: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=everyone